# Is the "X-Mailer: PHP/<phpversion>" header required to send a mail in PHP?

Tags: php

A lot of examples I found online about sending emails with php set the header

```
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()
```

But I find disclosing I'm using php and its version a very bad security practice.

Is this a required header?

Comment: Not as far as I know. What makes you think that it is? Are you finding that not having the header stops a mail being sent?

Comment: 99% of examples out there include it, so I'm not brave enough to test it in any of my live sites.

Comment: Try it in a non-live site? `:-)`

Comment: Obviously, but would like to know what the community thinks about it.

Comment: It's recommended but not required.

Comment: How can disclosing PHP version be a security hazard?
May be you could use any valid string there.

Comment: @SazzadTusharKhan The first think I think of disclosing that kind of information is by using known attack vectors on that specific PHP version

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's look at what kind of header is generated.

According to [RFC 2076](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2076.txt), section 3.4, the header "X-Mailer" is, together with several others, non-standard. Which basically means that any mail software can treat it like it wants to, especially adding them or ignoring them. Absence of such headers cannot be used against the sender.

I'm pretty sure the "X-" prefix indicates "non-standard header" in SMTP message format as well, just as it does in HTTP headers or mime types.

Answer (score 17):

I have to hit the minimum character limit.

NO :)

Answer (score 3):

Not required, but you must verify all the headers because some providers (hotmail, yahoo, orange in France) are increasingly stringent and mark it as spam legitimate emails more easily

Comment: What do you mean by "verify all the headers"? Is it a bad practice include/omit it?